# How to work with WebSockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to use WebSockets in PHP and Javascript and I'm confused, it uses the protocol **ws://** and **wss://** and the server (hostgator) not enabled these protocols (I think!) And I can not connect, someone know if I need to enable these protocols on the server or how do I connect?

**EDIT: It is possible to use websockets for streaming audio?**

I tried connecting to another server I found in examples and got ... 
Following code:

```
<script>

var connection = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/')

connection.onopen = function(e) {
  alert("Connected");
  console.log("Connected");
};

connection.onclose = function(e) {
  alert("Connection closed");
  console.log("Connection closed");
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help.

This is the programming assignment I made on PHP. Its a 2-way chat application which deploys a Client-Server on both the machines.

Client A talks to Server B
Client B talks to Server A

http://rishabhmehan.com/?attachment_id=255

This will be good for reference. It has the readme file in it, that can help you.

Also check this - http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP

Comment: It is possible to use websockets for streaming audio?

Comment: Well it is possible, why don't you look into WebRTC as well, or do you solely want it on PHP ??

Comment: Could be anyway, since that works, because I can not send the file that I record live in the blob ...